# Parsing JSON into RoseTree (recursive parsing)

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I am struggling with a function that would take `String` JSON as an input and return `RoseTree` structure as an output.

My code is as follows:

```
import qualified Data.Aeson as JSON
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Aeson.Types as AT
import Control.Applicative
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import Data.Attoparsec.ByteString.Char8

data RoseTree a = Empty | RoseTree a [RoseTree a]
                   deriving (Show)

instance (Show a) => JSON.ToJSON (RoseTree a) where
    toJSON (RoseTree n cs) =
        JSON.object [T.pack "value" JSON..= show n
        , T.pack "children" JSON..= JSON.toJSON cs] 

instance (Show a, JSON.FromJSON a) => JSON.FromJSON (RoseTree a) where
    parseJSON (JSON.Object o) =
        RoseTree <$> o JSON..: T.pack "value"
        <*> o JSON..: T.pack "children"

parseRoseTreeFromJSON :: (Show a, JSON.FromJSON a) => String -> (RoseTree a)
parseRoseTreeFromJSON json = 
      let bs = BS.pack json in case parse JSON.json bs of
               (Done rest r) -> case AT.parseMaybe JSON.parseJSON r of
                    (Just x) -> x
                    Nothing -> Empty 
               _ -> Empty
```

It converts `RoseTree` structure into JSON perfectly fine. For example, when I run `JSON.encode $ JSON.toJSON $ RoseTree 1 []`, it returns `"{\"children\":[],\"value\":\"1\"}"`, running `JSON.encode $ JSON.toJSON $ RoseTree 1 [RoseTree 2 []]` returns `"{\"children\":[{\"children\":[],\"value\":\"2\"}],\"value\":\"1\"}"`.

But when I try to supply that JSON I have got on the previous step into the parser, it always returns `Empty`:

```
*Main> parseRoseTreeFromJSON "{\"children\":[],\"value\":1}"
Empty

*Main> parseRoseTreeFromJSON "{\"children\":[{\"children\":[],\"value\":\"2\"}],\"value\":\"1\"}"
Empty
```

Similarly,

```
*Main> JSON.decode $ BLS.pack "{\"children\":[{\"children\":[],\"value\":\"2\"}],\"value\":\"1\"}"
Nothing
```

I suspect that my parser is incorrectly defined. But I cannot tell what exactly is wrong. Is the approach I am using  the correct one to approach recursive parsing? What would be the right way to do it recursively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weird GHCi typing rules strike again! Everything works as expected if you add type annotations:

```
ghci> :set -XOverloadedStrings
ghci> JSON.decode "{\"children\":[],\"value\":1}" :: Maybe (RoseTree Int)
Just (RoseTree 1 [])
```

Without knowing what type you are trying to parse (it sees `FromJSON a => Maybe a`), GHCi defaults `a ~ ()`. You can try this out by testing the `FromJSON ()` instance out and noticing that it succeeds!

```
ghci> JSON.decode "[]"
Just ()
```

---

Couple side notes on your code if this is actually for a project (and not just for fun and learning):

- I encourage you to check out `OverloadedStrings` (you can basically drop almost all uses of `T.pack` from your code since string literals will infer whether they should have type `String`, lazy/strict `Text`, lazy/strict `ByteString` etc.)
- You can use `DeriveGeneric` and `DeriveAnyClass` to get JSON parsing almost for free (although I concede the behavior will be *slightly* different from what you currently have)

With those suggestions, here is a rewrite of your code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, DeriveGeneric, DeriveAnyClass #-}

import qualified Data.Aeson as JSON
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as BS
import GHC.Generics (Generic)
import Data.Maybe (fromMaybe)

data RoseTree a = RoseTree { value :: a, children :: [RoseTree a] }
                    deriving (Show, Generic, JSON.FromJSON, JSON.ToJSON)
```

Note that `decode` from `Data.Aeson` does (almost) what `parseRoseTreeFromJSON` does...

```
ghci> :set -XOverloadedStrings
ghci> JSON.encode (RoseTree 1 [])
"{\"children\":[],\"value\":1}"
ghci> JSON.encode (RoseTree 1 [RoseTree 2 []])
"{\"children\":[{\"children\":[],\"value\":2}],\"value\":1}"
ghci> JSON.decode "{\"children\":[],\"value\":1}" :: Maybe (RoseTree Int)
Just (RoseTree {value = 1, children = []})
ghci> JSON.decode "{\"children\":[{\"children\":[],\"value\":2}],\"value\":1}" :: Maybe (RoseTree Int)
Just (RoseTree {value = 1, children = [RoseTree {value = 2, children = []}]})
```

Comment: How comes you don't need to do `BLS.pack`? :)

Comment: @altern Ooops. I always turn on `-XOverloadedStrings`. I'll make that clearer. :)